# How to cite author and long name of institution? (Harvard style)

Tags: harvard-style

I want to cite a paper by L. Wilkinson and the Task Force on Statistical Inference in Harvard style. Usually, I would cite a paper by two authors like this: "Pigs are clever (One/Two 2014)." But in this case "Pigs are clever (Wilkinson/Task Force on Statistical Inference 2014)." is potentially misleading. Who can help?

Comment: Please show the full bank bank b entry into n question, and please tell us which bibliography style you employ. Please also tell us if you use a citation management package (and, if so, which one).

Comment: There might be a solution, but it would be much appreciated if you could provide the full bib entry so we can work on it. Just edit your post accordingly.